# Viber notification doesn't disappear

Tags: notifications, viber-messenger

I use Viber on Android and when it is in the background, it shows a notification in the notification bar when I get a message.
However, sometimes when I click that message and it opens Viber, the notification stays there no matter that *I'm actually reading it*.

If I go to the message list, it shows unread messages, no matter I just read it. 
If I dismiss the message, it'll get back in a few minutes as it detects it is not yet read.

You can see here the notification is there and the message is already read:

[image]

What should I set to make it show the notifications properly?

Comment: I confirm, the **issue** is still present in version 5.1.

Comment: I confirm, the **issue** is still present in version 5.0.2.12

Comment: I confirm, the **issue** is still present in version 5.2.2.478

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me in my VIBER FOR DESKTOP (Windows).
(In my case the problem was caused by an unread CALL on viber; but I couldn't find it!!!)
This is how I located and solved the problem:
1.  I clicked on the conversations tab.
2.  Then clicked on the small triangle that appears in the corner
3.  I chose from the options:
    "Unread messages on top"
4.  Voila!!! The conversation came at the top, I clicked on it and the 'unread message' disappeared!